# My male cat is wanting me to follow him

Tags: cats, behavior

My male cat is almost 2yrs old and today for the first time ever he has been meowing A LOT and it's not his normal meows. He is also staying very close to me and won't leave my side and will run a little ahead of me and then look back to see if I'm following him (he has never done this). He is mostly an outside cat. He comes home in the morning, eats, lays around for a couple hours and then back outside he goes for the day, but today he acted completely different. So after I realized he wanted me to follow him outside, I did.

He kept running a little ahead of me making sure I'm following him and then he got to the spot where he stopped, looked at me and just started meowing while looking at me and towards the place he wanted me to go. Well the problem is he wants me to go underneath the apartments I live at and I obviously can't fit through the tiny little vents.

So long story short I'm not sure what he wants, maybe he's trying to show me something important or maybe he's just playing around but by the way he's meowing and so persistent that I follow him it doesn't seem like he's playing. Thank you.

Comment: the cat want some help from you there might be an other animal stuck under the building,you have to get sombody to help you look under the building,cats dont usualy drag their owners whith them if they dont have a problem.

Comment: Can you shine a flashlight through the vents? If there's an animal stuck under there you might see a reflection from their eyes.

Comment: Has he been spayed and nuderd, if not he may have had kittens and wants to show you them because he trusts you

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like he is trying to communicate with you and wants you to check something.
There may be another cat trapped down there, or kittens. I'd see if you can get someone to investigate.
As animals cannot speak to us with works, they need to use their sounds and actions as he has.
It would be interesting to see what's down there.

Answer (score 3):

Please find someone to help him look under there, especially if he is still doing it. Cats are very smart and can warn their owners about things like weather or foes, they can also sense emotions or imminent death.

He came back to get you because he knows and trusts you, he probably hasn't tried bringing anyone else to that spot. If you don't help him no one else will. It might not be serious (maybe he's showing you his baby momma) or perhaps an animal is hurt but either way you're the only one that knows this (vague) information and it is worth looking into :)